# How to add a certificate based credential to Windows Credential Manager?

Tags: ssl, windows-7, client-certificates, credential-manager

How do you add a certificate from the personal store as a certificate based credential in Windows `Credential Manager`?

When I click on "Open the Certificate Manager" it just takes me to the Certificate Manager and there is no way to actually select the certificate to be added as a certificate based credential.

It doesn't make any difference what I type in "Internet or network address".  When I press "Select certificate" it just asks me to insert a smart card.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In certmgr, right-click the client certificate, choose "Enable only the following purposes", and disable `Smart Card Logon` and `Any Purpose` (which seems to include Smart Card Logon). (Or, disable everything except `Client Authentication`).

[image]

Obviously, if `Smart Card Logon` is enabled, the credential manager won't use the certificate without a smartcard.

Answer (score 0):

Click Open the Certificate Manager to view the Current User Certificates.
Provide the resource and click Select Certificate and Ok.

[image]
[image]

6. Windows Vault contains credentials for servers, websites and programs that windows can try to log you on to automatically.

[image]
Click Back up vault.
Browse the location to store Windows Vault backup. Click Next.

Answer (score -2):

In Windows 7 you can add certificate based credential. To learn just follow these steps

**Step 1:** Click on `Start button` and then `Control Panel`

**Step 2:** In Control Panel Click on `Credential Manager`
[image]

**Step 3:** Click on `Add` a `Certificate-Based Credential`

[image]

**Step 4:** Fill up the block Select `certificate` and then Click on `OK`

[image]

**step 5:** 
Then you can go ahead and `enter the DNS Name` for the machine on your network as well as the `username` and `password` you would like to connect with, then click the `Ok` button.

**step 6:**
You will now see that you credential has been added to the vault.

**Note:**
Windows does cache your login credentials when connecting to another machine, however they are not persistent, this means that they wont survive a reboot, luckily the Credential Manager came to our rescue.

Comment: The above steps don't work. When I click on "Select certificate" it asks me to insert a smart card.

Comment: when you click select certificate it ask you for connect a smart card for that you need smart card there is no other way, with out smart card